# how to get integers or number entries from excel to database through php

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

```
$object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES["excel_file"]["tmp_name"]);  
           foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)  
           {  
                $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();  
                for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)  
                {  
                     $school_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());  
                     $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());  
                     $middlename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue());  
                     $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue());
```

It shows all the datas except for school_number.

Comment: so what's the output of var_dump($school_number); ? And show an example for your spreadsheet.

Comment: school_number firstname  middlename  lastname
12312312         qqqqq       qqqqq          qqqq
12413                 wwww         wwww          eeeee
2331212                 wwwwwaawe aaaa          aaaa

Comment: the output shows only the list of firstname mn and lastname. it doesnt show the list of school_number. sorry to type the input like this coz i can't post a photo in here